# how to call a class, after_create method from either a spec or rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
    after_create TellMe
end

class TellMe
  def self.after_create(model)
end
```

and would like to be able to do something analogous to this:

```
i=Item.new :name => 'my test name'
i.send(:TellMe.after_create)
```

similar to how I could call send on a public method? It looks like I can do

```
i.instance_eval 'TellMe.after_create(self)'
```

but feels a little ugly (amongst other things)

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Can you put it in context with real code?

Comment: the above is pretty close to an actual call if you had `after_create :tell_me` you could have `Item.send(:tell_me)` and use in various contexts. Would like to just have access to this function in similar manner. Prob a dumb question

Answer (score 1):

The only way to trigger a callback is to do a qualifying event, in this case, creating an item.

As a workaround to what you want, you could just create another method that will do exactly what the callback would do and you would be able to access it like normal

```
Class Item < ActiveRecord::Base

  def tellme(params)
    TellMe.function(params)
  end

end
```

Comment: it being a callback isn't really of relavance here, is it. I am trying to just call it with the context of the current model. That's my impression of what send does. Am I missing something?

Comment: You can simply just pass whatever parameters you want into the function. Inside the class function you have access to all of that model's data via `self`.